# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://myappurl.com is therefore not allowed access

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios

I'm coding a vue app and using a Node.js Api. I already included cors in backend and others post methods works well. But in this route has a Nginx 502 Bad Gateway.

The error in console of chrome is

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)

Failed to load : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 502.
```

The app.js CORS

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false")

  next();
});
```

My [AddPatient](https://pastebin.com/JMZae4A0) component and my [Axios](https://pastebin.com/hYE5wegk)  available on pastebin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `setHeader` you are writing only **one** header, overwriting the previous. You have to use `res.header()` that allows you to write multiple headers. You can do it this way:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false")

  next();
});
```

Comment: Adding to that, the *only* allowed value for Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is *true*. Either don't pass it, or pass it as true.

Comment: That’s not true, you can specify a value like an URL for the header